# Prove that the following structure is a group. $(G,*)$ where $G = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $x*y$ is defined to be remainder when $xy$ is divided by 5.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that the following structure is a group.   $(G,*)$ where $G = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $x*y$ is defined to be remainder when $xy$ is divided by 5.

My Approach:
It satisfies closure property.
It satisfies associativity property.
Identity element exists (i.e. $e = 1$)
Inverse for ${1,2,3,4}$ is ${1,3,2,4}$ respectively.

Is my inverse part correct?

This doubt came because there was a similar problem and the inverse in that case was a closed form formula ( $(R,*)$ where $R$ is set of real numbers and $x * y = x + y -1$. In this case inverse was $Inverse(x)=  2-x$).

But in case of $(G,*)$, I'm not able to figure out closed form formula.
Please correct me if, I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: We don't need a closed formula—your enumeration of the inverses is enough.

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you sir.

Comment: Actually, the set that you working on is called $\mathbb Z_5$, you can generalize this by $n$

Comment: I think it's rather denoted with $\Bbb Z_5^\times$, @nozalp10, as usually $\Bbb Z_5$ stands for $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z, +)$.

Comment: yes, you are right